# Gap between bars C3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I want to put gaps between bars. 
I tried ; 
        
`...
          bar:{
              width: {
                  ratio: 0.5
              }
          },
...`

The code above didn't work for me. 
The question is: why doesn't it work or how can I make it work?

Comment: You are going to have to try a little harder on your question.  Coding up a [minimal example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pYOAwsBmnUaXlZtQWAaw?p=preview) and I can show that the option works just fine.  Why doesn't it work for you, no one will ever know **until you reproduce the problem for us**.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** some thing like:

```js
 

var colors = ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e'];


var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['value: ', 20, 14, 3]
    ],
    type: 'bar',
    labels: true,

    color: function(color, d) {
      return colors[d.index];
    }

  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: 'category',
      categories: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']
    }
  },
  bar: {
    width: {
      ratio: 0.5,
    }
  },
  grid: {
    focus: {
      show: false
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.5/c3.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.6/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.5/c3.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ratio doesn't put a gap between the bars, it is basically 5 lines of code that doesn't do anything. Maybe I should just use D3.js for that part  @MMK

Comment: I found out what's going on. The data is pushed to my c3 code as a block so I have 9 bars and it accepts all 9 bars as one, when I put ratio it makes it smaller or bigger as a block. What I need when it is grouped like this putting a gap between the bars. (in data part grouped: false, that doesn't solve the issue)

Comment: Another way of saying that:
data is not received as columns:[['data1', 20,30,30]]
it is received as columns: [ ['data1', 20], ['data2', 30]  ]